# Matplotlib offsetbox fails to show grayscaled image

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-image

As title says, I'm trying to show 8-bit grayscaled .bmp image in matplotlibs annotationbbox but for some reason the result is undesired. I also resized the image with skimage's function called resize which can also affect to the result. The reason for failed result is that annotated image is normalized so that the darkest pixel get color black and lightest pixel gets color white.

Here are example code, original image and the result of the plot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import offsetbox
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from skimage.transform import resize

image = np.array(Image.open('testimage.bmp'))

#Black color is converted to white color
for i in range(image.shape[0]):
    for j in range(image.shape[1]):
        image[i][j] = 255 - image[i][j]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(300, 200),dpi=40)
shown_images = np.array([[1., 1.]])  # just something big
imagebox = offsetbox.AnnotationBbox(
        offsetbox.OffsetImage(resize(image, (540,940), order=1, preserve_range=True),cmap="Greys"),[0.5,0.5])
ax.add_artist(imagebox)
plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

**Original image**
[image]

**Annotated image**

[image]

Hopefully I'm just missing something obvious...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would want to set the normalization of the image to the range you expect it to be, in this case probably `0` to `255`.

```
offsetbox.OffsetImage(image, norm=plt.Normalize(0,255), cmap="Greys")
```